# Save Dynamic View ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Core and am trying to make make a page that has a dynamic text box based on what a dropdown selection is. The dropdown selection changes the input type of what a user is sumbitting. Code:

```
<form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var searchSelection = document.getElementById("searchSelection");
        var rewardsBox = document.getElementById("userId");
        var emailBox = document.getElementById("email");
        var phoneBox = document.getElementById("phone");

        rewardsBox.style.display = searchSelection.value == "userId" ? "block" : "none";
        emailBox.style.display = searchSelection.value == "email" ? "block" : "none";
        phoneBox.style.display = searchSelection.value == "phone" ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>

<select class="form-control" id="searchSelection" onchange="ShowHideDiv()">
    <option value="userId">ID</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="value">Value:</label>
        <div id="userId" style="display:block">
            <input asp-for="UserId" type="text" class="form-control clearable" id="idText" Placeholder="0123456789">
        </div>
        <div id="email" style="display:none">
            <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control clearable" id="emailText" Placeholder="janedoe@hallmark.com">
        </div>
        <div id="phone" style="display:none">
            <input asp-for="Phone" type="text" class="form-control clearable" id="phoneText" Placeholder="8751239876">
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the code returns a view with the retrieved user(s) and the form stays on the page. The form stays filled out, which is what I want, but the dropdown re-sets itself to ID as the selected value and showing the text box for ID (which is expected since it's a new View). Is there a way to save the view so what was selected and then changed with the javascript will appear in the new view?

Comment: Please include the code for your action also. The one processing the form submission.

Comment: you can save this fields in your model, emailBox, phoneBox, dropdown, etc and when return to view, you should pass this model, and  select list you pass this property stored